# What does -= operator mean in scala def context

Tags: scala

I discovered the below odd def definition syntax in Kafka source code . Can somebody help me understand this syntax as I am unable to find in scala documents. The first def definition works but the second one does not work

```
  private def test_=(x: Int) {

  }

  private def test=(x: Int) {

  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the source?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/cluster/Replica.scala   (line 64)

Comment: I can find only `private def logEndOffset_=(newLogEndOffset: LogOffsetMetadata)` and def `logEndOffset =
    if (isLocal)` but nothing like `logEndOffset=(newLogEndOffset: LogOffsetMetadata)
    if (isLocal)`, so it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: @dk14 Yes, you are right it is not there, initially,when  def test_= syntax didn't give any error, I just wanted to check whether def test= would also work, but it gave errors so I wanted to know the significance of _= under def context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't an operator. There is just a special rule that if you have a method with a name ending in `_=` and a single argument, *and* a no-argument method with the same name without `_=`(in this case `def test = ...`), then Scala will understand `foo.test = ...` as the `foo.test_=(...)` call.

Comment: There's another rule - identifiers in Scala may contain special characters, but letters and special characters have to be separated by an underscore, otherwise the compiler will complain - and this is exactly why `test_=` is a valid identifier while `test=` is not.